# Disable add to cart button on specific products

Tags: magento2, addtocart

On the product page, I want to disable add to cart button on specific products.

Comment: You can create simple product attribute with Value Yes/No and set it to product and based on boolean value you can set condition inside addtocart.phtml file

Comment: Thanks, I have created attribute with name 'Disable add to cart''. Now in addtocart.phtml file, how I will call this attribute? Can you please tell me the code for it.

Comment: Can you share your attribute code?

Comment: I have created attribute with value Yes/No from the admin panel by going to Stores --> Attributes

Comment: did you check your attribute_code for above attributes? based on those attributes we need required to add condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep below code in your addtocart.phtml file,
**if your attribute name is disable_add_to_cart,**

```
<?php if ($_product->getDisableAddToCart()): ?>   
    <div class="box-tocart">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="number"
                           name="qty"
                           id="qty"
                           maxlength="12"
                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                           />
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit"
                        title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                        class="action primary tocart"
                        id="product-addtocart-button">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
                </button>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, I have created only attribute set "disableAddToCart".

Comment: please add $_product->getDisableAddToCart() in condition in above mytypo mistake. Use getDisableAddToCart()